# In ASP.NET, Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-webapi, preflight

I am using a Web Core API and have set up CORS as follows;

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors();
        ...
    }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
var url = Configuration["origenUrl"];
            var header = "Content-Type";
            app.UseCors(
                options => options.WithOrigins(url).WithHeaders(header).AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials()
            );
        }
```

This setup works fine for Get Requests.
But for my Put request;

```
   $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "PUT",
        xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }
    })
        .done(callback)
        //.fail(errorMessage);
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Something went wrong: " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
            errorCallback();
        });
```

I get this error message;

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:17972/api/fault/1/close.
>
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:12528' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

From Fiddler my http request is;

> OPTIONS http://localhost:17972/api/fault/10/close HTTP/1.1
>
> Accept: */*
>
> Origin: http://localhost:12528
>
> Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT
>
> Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept
>
> UA-CPU: AMD64
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64;Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
>
> Host: localhost:17972
>
> Content-Length: 0
>
> DNT: 1
>
> Connection: Keep-Alive
>
> Pragma: no-cache

So how do I fix this?

EDIT
I have also tried this code just to get it working, but I get the same error;

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            //var url = Configuration["originUrl"];
            //app.UseCors(
            //    options => options.WithOrigins(url).AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials()
            //);
            app.UseCors(
                options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials()
            );
            app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: Did you add the content-type?

Comment: I put "Content-Type" in the header variable which is then included in the WithHeaders method as you can see in the code. I have since tried "AnyHeader()" with the same result.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain so fin, I was speaking about the request. Do you have a raw HTTP request?

Comment: From Fiddler: OPTIONS http://localhost:17972/api/fault/10/close HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Origin: http://localhost:12528
Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept
UA-CPU: AMD64
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host: localhost:17972
Content-Length: 0
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

Answer (score 3):

Try with AllowAnyHeader instead of WithHeaders, it must works.
The problem is that you are requiring a "Content-Type" header, but isn't being sent.
If you wants to keep the WithHeaders check, add "Access-Control-Request-Method".

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors

Comment: I tried that but to no avail. I have been looking at the link - which is a good one - for some time trying to work out what I can do.

Comment: You can also avoid libraries and add a cors rule in the web.config here:  https://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: To try and get it working I am now using AllowAnyOrigin() but this does not solve the problem

Comment: Still the same problem? can you update your question with the new code?

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar problem where GET requests would work fine, but POST requests would give me the same angry message as OP got.
The code below worked for me, the other answers weren't quite complete in my case:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddDefaultPolicy(
            builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:1337")
                       .AllowAnyHeader()
                       .AllowAnyMethod();
            });
    });

    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddRazorPages();
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit old, but I just ran into the same problem and was able to work out the issue. I was following a Microsoft guide on how to enable CORS globally. I set the following code within the Startup.cs file...

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
        builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost");
        });
});
```

The guide did have an example of using a localhost, however it was at the very end within the "Test CORS" section. There, they show that you have to have the port number as well.
I changed my code to:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
        builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                .AllowAnyHeader();
        });
});
```

I also added the AllowAnyHeader (as mentioned above) and everything works great!
HTH